# Comment through Facebook Plugins are posting on my website, but not on the Facebook page

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments, posting

I am trying to add a **Facebook comments box** on my webpage.

I have tried several different plugins and they all have the same problem:  When I try to comment on the facebook page in question through my website, *the comment shows up on my website, but not on the Facebook page.*
I have inputted the correct Facebook app ID and facebook page URL into the plugins. 
 I don't understand what I am doing wrong.  I am using **Rapidweaver** as a web design program.  Please help (and note that I am very new to this and not a programmer).

Comment: have you tried this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ ? this  plugin worked for me.. fb comment was appeared both in fb page as well as in webpage..

Answer (score 0):

The comments will never show up on your Facebook page.

The comments plugin is a social interaction on your site, so users comment on your site *not* your Facebook page. No plugin will double post comments unless you explicitly ask for access from the user to post on your Facebook page. From what I have seen so far, no such plugin exists.

For more info: Read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/